# users created using newusers command unable to login in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login

**background:**

I am planning to create a list of users for a newly setup Ubuntu 18.04 server and thinking to create the users one by one manually will be time-consuming hence I am thinking to use **newusers** command but face problems after the command is successfully executed

**errors**

after running the following command:

```
newusers [file-path]
```

the contents for the file looks like below:

```
user_1:password_1:1001:1001:user_1:/home/user_1:/bin/bash
user_2:password_2:1002:1002:user_2:/home/user_2:/bin/bash
```

the error I face is that I am able to log in as user_2 but not able to log in as user_1 and the error I am facing is: No such file or directory

could anyone able to point out what may be the mistakes I made?

**screenshot of the errors**
[image]

Comment: Is that the *entire* error? or does it say something like `/bin/bash: No such file or directory`?

Comment: @steeldriver pls see my edit, I have added an screenshot of error

Comment: Thanks - can you also post the output of `getent passwd user_1  | cat -A` please? I *suspect* the issue is that your `singleuser.txt` file had DOS-style CRLF line endings that messed up the login shell entry for the user.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for your help, end up I forgot to convert the DOS-style line endings to Unix, after amending, the problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if the file passed to the `newusers` command has DOS-style (CRLF) line endings that cause the new user's login shell to be recorded as `/bin/bash\r` for example.

Ex.

```
$ cat > singleuser.txt
user_1:password_2:1002:1002:user_1:/home/user_1:/bin/bash

$ unix2dos singleuser.txt 
unix2dos: converting file singleuser.txt to DOS format ...

$ sudo newusers singleuser.txt 
[sudo] password for steeldriver: 

$ sudo su - user_1
: No such file or directory

$ getent passwd user_1 | cat -A
user_1:x:1002:1002:user_1:/home/user_1:/bin/bash^M$
```

You can fix already existing users using `chsh`:

```
$ sudo chsh -s /bin/bash user_1
$ sudo su - user_1
user_1@xenial-vm:~$
```